# Upload file to Amazon S3 with access key and secret, without using SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Is there an S3 endpoint which will take the access key, secret, and the file in the body, and then accept the file upload? I would rather not import the entire AWS SDK for just minimal operations.

My use case: I have an AWS lambda function which uploads files to S3. At the moment, I use the AWS SDK for the file upload, but this makes the lambda function package size larger than actually required, since I need to upload aws-sdk npm package along with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an S3 endpoint which will take the access key, secret, and the file in the body, and then accept the file upload? I would rather not import the entire AWS SDK for just minimal operations.

You never pass the access key and secret directly to the AWS API. You have to [sign your requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing-aws-api-requests.html) with the key and secret. It is much easier to use the SDK than write custom request signing code.

However, the AWS SDK is [included in the AWS Lambda runtime environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html). You don't need to upload the SDK as part of your Lambda function deployment unless you need a different version of the SDK than the one provided in the runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! here is the AWS S3 official RestAPI documentation
[AWS s3 restAPI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).